# How to fix example javascript code; error: ReferenceError: require is not defined?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run some example code [linked here](https://github.com/bpostlethwaite/colormap), but upon start I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I know, `require.js` is some package for javascript, but it is not mentioned anywhere on the example page? It says just to throw in the javascript code in nsome html skeleton and it should work! Is there a way to fix the code so it does not that extra package?

I also downloaded `require.js` myself from somewere, put it in the same directory, included it in the html, and got an error

```
Error: Module name "colormap" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

*in* `require.js`!

Comment: last line of the readme mention `browserify`

Comment: What is that? Never heard before!

Answer (score 1):

The code you linked is written for NodeJS

But as the readme suggests you can get it to run if you package it using browserify (https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)

Assuming you have NodeJS installed, you need to install browserify globally using NPM (Node Package Manager that comes with NodeJS)

Open a console and run `npm install -g browserify` - This will add the browserify command to your console.

Next up we need to create our on Node Package

1. Make a new directory
2. cd into that directory and run `npm init` - this will start a guide that will ask you to fill in some information about your package and creates a `package.json` file
3. run `npm install --save bpostlethwaite/colormap` this will install the colormap library you are interested in
4. Create an index.js file (assuming you left that unchanged when you run npm init)
5. Paste the example code from the read me in index.js
6. Finally run `browserify -s index.js > bundle.js` - This will generate a bundle.js file that can run in a browser

Hope that helps

Comment: What does 'browserify' mean? Never heard before!

Comment: browserify is a tool that takes a code written for nodejs and packages all their dependencies (it creates a bundle.js) so that they can be run inside a browser.

Comment: Do I need to install this? Or can I just put the code in some online service which spits out the bundeled code?

Comment: How to I know when to do this? In the example it is mentioned, but otherwise? How can I see it requires node.js?

Comment: Can't the code just load node.js from some authorative web source?

Comment: you need to have nodejs installed in order to use this library(colormap) and browserify which will then export a bundle for you to run in browser. it's honestly very simple. Let me update my answer

Comment: You still update the answer? I only have 15 minutes left. If I get it to work in 15 minutes then I agree its easy...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94944/discussion-between-alex-and-dogoku).

Comment: Still does not work, get the same error "ReferenceError: require is not defined".

Comment: I coded my own colormap functions in the meantime. Took only 30 minutes!

Comment: just because something is open source, doesn't mean is always the best solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the last issue that you get `Use require([])` you must to define like this:

```
 require(['colormap'], function() {
     // colormap is now loaded
 });
```

Comment: Do I need to put this code instead of `var cmap = require('colormap')`?

Comment: yes. According with the documentation of the error you must to define as an item of an array, so `var cmap = require(['colormap'])` should remove the error.