# How to run javascript colormap example?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

In order to try a javascript example I found [here](https://github.com/bpostlethwaite/colormap), I did the following things (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674877/how-to-fix-example-javascript-code-error-referenceerror-require-is-not-define), on Windows 7):

1. Installed `node`
2. Installed `browserify`.
3. Created a new directory `Test`.
4. Within this directory I run `npm init`.
5. Within this directory I created a file `index.js` with the exact content as shown on the [example page](https://github.com/bpostlethwaite/colormap) ate the bottom.
6. I ran the following commands:

   ```
   npm install colormap
   browserify -s index.js > bundle.js
   ```
7. I created a html code `example.html` as follows (in the same directory):

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>   
   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
   <img id="background" readsrc="satellite-view-of-earth-at-night.jpg" width=480></img>
   <img id="canvasImg" name="colormap" alt="image for download">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>          
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
8. opened the file `example.html` and just saw an empty blank white page with the text `image for download`. No colormaps. No error on the konsole either!

How to fix this code, how to do it right? Maybe I did forget to install something? Did something in the wrong order? Forgot to do something else?

Comment: What is the bundle.js file?

Comment: No idea - it is created in step 6. Its probably the 'browserified' version of `index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

**colormap** is a NPM module for *generating* colormaps.  It includes a few pre-generated colormaps in the \res directory, but in general you need to do something like the following to generate a json array which represents a colormap. After steps 1 to 6 above, create a new .js file with the following contents and run it to create a custom colormap:

```
let colormap = require('colormap')
var fs = require('fs');

let colors = colormap({
    colormap: 'jet',
    nshades: 256,
    format: 'hex',
    alpha: [1.0, 0.5, 1.0]
})

var json_text = JSON.stringify(colors);

fs.writeFile("jet.json", json_text, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```